# sIFR works, except for one word in my navigation bar

Tags: sifr

My website uses sIFR and it all seems to work great, except for one word in my navigation bar. The navigation links all work, but the word "Zoeken" (= Search) in front of the search form doesn't get changed to the desired font type.
I have checked the header.php of my site, as well as the CSS, but any of the changes that I made, don't seem to work.
Could anyone help me out? I am hoping it's just a "piece of cake", but my knowledge of sIFR is close to non-existent.
Many thanks!
Jasper

Comment: Could you post the page in question?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a class to this element Zoeken and then target that span specifically with cufon to see if it works, maybe?  As cufon is really simple and if it's not converting it the only thing I can think of is that it's not being targetted.  If the above doesn't work it'll also give you a better idea of what the problem is.

Comment: +1 for recommending Cufon, which is far better in many aspects than sIFR.

Comment: I know, my life got better the day I discovered it :)

Comment: Thank you! The other words are already sIFR'ed, so it would have my preference for now to use the same approach with that very last word. I will look at cufon as well though!

Cheers :)